# Build failing when including the Openshift Java RESTClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

I have a project using Spring, and as soon as I include the below in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.openshift</groupId>
<artifactId>openshift-restclient-java</artifactId>
<version>6.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the below set of errors. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/m/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/m/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/m/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/m/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/Users/m/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:637)
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:286)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:191)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:170)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319)
        at com.g2.automationstation.AutomationstationApp.main(AutomationstationApp.java:63)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: clean m2() repo and try again

Comment: Are you using `slf4j-log4j12` and `logback` as a dependency in your pom.xml? You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to see what dependencies are actually loaded for this project. And after that you may manually exclude some of them to prevent existence of `slf4j` and `logback` at the same time.

Comment: I deleted the entire .m2 repository, ran the mvn build again and it downloaded a bunch of stuff, but i still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Spring boot and the Openshift library use slf4j, which is a logging bridge framework. However, they both include a different bindings:

- Spring boot includes Logbback
- Openshift includes log4j

You can fix this by excluding either one of them, for example:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.openshift</groupId>
    <artifactId>openshift-restclient-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.3.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```